# Is there a difference between adding a scalar to a vector inside a for loop and outside it, using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, array-broadcasting

I was trying to take advantage of the Broadcasting property of Python while replacing the for loop of this snippet:

```
import numpy as np
B = np.random.randn(10,1)
k = 25
for i in range(len(B)):
  B[i][0]= B[i][0] + k
```

with this:

```
for i in range((lenB)):
  B=B+k
```

I observed that I was getting different results. When I tried outside the loop, B = B+k, gave the same results as what I was expecting with B[i][0] = B[i][0] + k

Why is this so? Does Broadcasting follow different rules inside loops?

Comment: I think you have a typo.  'for in in range(len(B))'?  Also, are you using numpy?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] by initialising `B` and `k` helpfully. Fix the seeming mistakes around `in` and `lenB` if they are not also in the code you are asking about. Add all relevant imports.

Comment: broadcasting is associated with `numpy`, Python itself doesn't really have a notion of "scalar" vs "vector"

Comment: Surely you are now adding `k` multiple times.  Remove the loop.

Comment: B=B+k is looping k times and adding each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd option you ment to do the following:

```
B=B+k
```

As you see, you don't need the `for` loop and it is **MUCH** faster than looping over the "*vector*" (`numpy` array).

It is some form of "Vectorization" calculation instead of iterative calculation which is better in terms of complexity and readability. Both will yield the same result.

You can see a lot of examples on Vectorization vs Iteration, including running time, **[here](https://hackernoon.com/speeding-up-your-code-2-vectorizing-the-loops-with-numpy-e380e939bed3)**.

And you can see a **[great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKcLaGdvabM&t=120s)** of *Andrew Ng* going over *numpy broadcasting* property.